# IEnumerable<List<T>> to List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I'm working on a query of in-memory objects:

```
var rankingSummary = resultSet
                    .Where(r => r.Accuracy >= 95 && r.Accuracy <= 105)
                    .Select(r => r.Results).Where(r => r.ResultType == 1)
                    .Select(r => r.Subjects)
```

`Subjects` is a `List<Subject>` property that the Result class has. Where I'm at now in the query is with an `IEnumerable<List<Subject>>`. What I would like is for them to all be joined into a single List as I have further querying to do based on the properties of each Subject. Is there an elegant or practical way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
var rankingSummary = resultSet
                    .Where(r => r.Accuracy >= 95 && r.Accuracy <= 105)
                    .Select(r => r.Results).Where(r => r.ResultType == 1)
                    .SelectMany(r => r.Subjects)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: That's what I needed, thanks. And 2 identical answers at the same time, wish I could accept both.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var rankingSummary = resultSet
                .Where(r => r.Accuracy >= 95 && r.Accuracy <= 105)
                .Select(r => r.Results).Where(r => r.ResultType == 1)
                .SelectMany(r => r.Subjects)
                .ToList();
```